# PyInstaller error FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have python file with GUI I created using PySimpleGUI. I used PyInstaller to create an exe file for windows (and UNIX executable file on Mac) I get this error
"FileNotFoundError: No such file or directory"

```
window = sg.Window('Loading please wait...', layout, resizable=False, size=(400, 100), finalize=True)

model1 = keras.models.load_model('mymodels/model1.h5'))
model2 = joblib.load("mymodels/model2.joblib")
model3 = joblib.load("mymodels/model3.joblib")
window.close()
```

Comment: is the `mymodels` directory in the current working directory when executing the app?

Comment: @Alexander yes it's